# Angular Material Datepicker with Range Selection

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I'm using angular 8 and I wanted implement a datepicker with daterage highlighted:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFmaT.png)
I was looking for some package like this one:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/saturn-datepicker
Unfortunately it has been deprecated and currently I cannot find others like that.
Do you know something for my purpose? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**, My good!! google is plenty full of controls like mine! (remember: Google is my friend, google is my friend...)

I'm making a datePicker range in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-material-starter-template-q8dsfq?file=src/app/date-picker-range.ts), i'll try to explain after

**Update** I improve the stackblitz and a brief explanation

There are a point important with the mat-date-picker that it's not possible create a day-template. So it's necesary use Renderer2 to add listener, add classes or remove classes. I need use document.querySelectorAll as it's show in [this another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59458789/angular-material-date-picker-how-to-show-the-title/59461291#59461291)

The idea is, with the cells selected create an array of object

```
{
   date: //will be a getTime of the date,
   element: //will be the nativeElement x,
   change: //a boolean to indicate this cell has an aditional class
   x.listen: //the listener added to allow us remove the listener
}
```

And a function who help us to add/remove class acording two variables: this._dateTo and another variable that will be this._dateFrom or another one (early we discovered why)

```
  redrawCells(timeTo: number) {
    timeTo = timeTo || this._dateTo;
    if (timeTo<this._dateFrom)
      timeTo=this._dateFrom
    this.cells.forEach(x => {
      const change = x.date >= this._dateFrom && x.date <= timeTo;
      if (change || x.change) {
        x.change = change;
        const addInside = x.change ? "addClass" : "removeClass";
        const addFrom = x.date == this._dateFrom? "addClass":
                        x.date == timeTo && this._dateFrom==timeTo? "addClass":
                        "removeClass";
        const addTo = x.date == timeTo? "addClass": 
                      x.date == this._dateFrom && this._dateFrom==timeTo? "addClass":
                        "removeClass";

        this.renderer[addInside](x.element, "inside");
        this.renderer[addFrom](x.element, "from");
        this.renderer[addTo](x.element, "to");
      }
    });
  }
```

A new function setCell will be who manage the td to add/remove listener of mouse over. It's necesary enclosed in a setTimeout because we call this function before the calendar is drawed

```
  setCells() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.cells) {
        this.cells.forEach(x => {
          x.listen();  //<---remove the listener
        });
      }
      this.dateOver = null;
      //get the elements
      let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".calendar");
      if (!elements || elements.length == 0) return;
      const cells = elements[0].querySelectorAll(".mat-calendar-body-cell");
      this.cells = [];
      //with each element we fill our array "this.cells"
      cells.forEach((x, index) => {
        const date = new Date(x.getAttribute("aria-label"));
        const time=new Date(date.getFullYear() +"-" +(date.getMonth() + 1) +
              "-" +date.getDate()).getTime()

        this.cells.push({
          date: time,
          element: x,
          change:time>=this._dateFrom && time<=this._dateTo
        });
      });
      this.cells.forEach(x => {
        if (!x.listen) {
          //we add a listener "mouseover"
          x.listen = this.renderer.listen(x.element, "mouseover", () => {
            if (!this._dateTo && this.dateOver != x.date) {
              this.dateOver = x.date;
              this.redrawCells(this.dateOver); //who call to redrawCells
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Well, the rest of function necesary to parse and format a date and open a mat-calendar using a mat-menu is from [this another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202061/is-there-a-way-to-customize-angular-date-picker/60205304#60205304). In this last SO, the calendar not close, so, we can use to force two clicks to get a dateFrom and a dateTo

```
  select(date: any) {
    date = new Date(
      date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate()
    );
    if (
      !this.from.value ||
      (this.from.value && this.to.value) ||
      this._dateFrom > date.getTime()
    ) {
      this.dateFrom = date;
      this.dateTo = null;
      this.redrawCells(date.getTime());
    } else {
      this.dateTo = date;
      this.trigger.closeMenu();
    }
  }
```

I like create a mat custom component. This allow us use the component in a mat-form-field, some like

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width" >
  <mat-label>Select dates</mat-label>
  <date-picker-range [formControl]="control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"  ></date-picker-range>
  <mat-error>required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

And allow e.g. us use [disabled] to disabled the formControl, and the label move like another mat-input. For this we need add some functions, see (I promise it's the last) this [last recent SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223829/is-there-any-dropdown-available-with-filter-feature-in-angular-material-nb-usi/60249294#60249294)

NOTE: The control is "AS IS" without any warranty and it's allowed: critics it, improve, modify, use or put it as bad example

Answer (score 1):

In material date picker you can define max and min values.

For example:

> example.hml 
>   `<input matInput [min]="minValue" [max]="maxValue" [matDatepicker]="picker" 
>              formControlName="name"/>
>            <mat-datepicker #voltageToDatePiker [startAt]="tomorrow"></mat-datepicker>`
>
> example.ts
>   `minValue = new Date();`
>      `maxValue = new Date();`

Answer (score 0):

In angular material there is an option to specify range
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-range-selection

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
  <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
    <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date">
    <input matEndDate placeholder="End date">
  </mat-date-range-input>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
</mat-form-field>
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/pydjpbqmvqq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-overview-example.html