# How to implement ranged inline calendar with angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to use material calendar as a ranged inline calendar to display and insert date ranges.
When using mat-date-range-picker, this is just working (but not inline).
When using mat-calendar, it is working for inline, but not for ranged.
But if I pass selectedRangeValue as DateRange instead of Date, the Range is displayed properly.

The only thing still missing is input...

This is the code I use now (abbreviated):

```
<mat-calendar (selectedChange)="selectedRangeChange($event)"
              [selected]="selectedRangeValue"
>
</mat-calendar>
```

```
selectedRangeValue: DateRange<Date> =  new DateRange<Date>(this.selectedValue.begin, this.selectedValue.end);
```

I have to do this because Saturn Date picker is only supported until Angular 9, and from Angular 10 onwards Material Datepicker supports date ranges.
But this "inline date range calendar" I just cannot make work...

I found https://github.com/angular/components/issues/20697 where the same problem is described and a solution was found, but not written down, so that does not help.

I also tried to understand the source code of angular material datepicker, but unfortunately I still don't get it. I would appreciate any help or hints.

Answer (score 6):

The suggested solution has so much extra code, and more importantly it wasn't working for me. Here's a stripped working version.

HTML

```
<mat-calendar [selected]="selectedRangeValue"
  (selectedChange)="selectedChange($event)">
</mat-calendar>
```

TS

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { DateRange } from '@angular/material/datepicker';

@Component({
    selector: 'inline-range-calendar',
    templateUrl: './inline-range-calendar.component.html',
})
export class InlineRangeCalendarComponent {

    @Input() selectedRangeValue: DateRange<Date> | undefined;
    @Output() selectedRangeValueChange = new EventEmitter<DateRange<Date>>();

    selectedChange(m: any) {
        if (!this.selectedRangeValue?.start || this.selectedRangeValue?.end) {
            this.selectedRangeValue = new DateRange<Date>(m, null);
        } else {
            const start = this.selectedRangeValue.start;
            const end = m;
            if (end < start) {
                this.selectedRangeValue = new DateRange<Date>(end, start);
            } else {
                this.selectedRangeValue = new DateRange<Date>(start, end);
            }
        }
        this.selectedRangeValueChange.emit(this.selectedRangeValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: That looks much more concise, thanks for sharing!
I work on other things now, but I will ask  my colleagues to check this and change our code accordingly

Comment: @JulianEgner thank you for the first version though, I started from there :)

Comment: Great! I had the hope that the code might help someone, because it took several days to find a solution.

Comment: can you please provide stackblitz for your solution?

Comment: Nice Solution, I wish I could have knew it before

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve this. While I am not sure if this is the best way, I want to provide the solution.

I had to create a new angular component for the inline ranged calendar:

HTML Schema

```
<mat-calendar
  #calendar
  [selected]="selectedRangeValue"
  (selectedChange)="selectedChange($event)"
>
</mat-calendar>
```

Typescript

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {
  DateRange, DefaultMatCalendarRangeStrategy,
  MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY, MatCalendar,
} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {isNullOrUndefined} from '../../util/is-null-or-undefined';
import moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
  selector: 'inline-range-calendar',
  templateUrl: './inline-range-calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inline-range-calendar.component.sass'],
  providers: [{
    provide: MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY,
    useClass: DefaultMatCalendarRangeStrategy
  }]
})
export class InlineRangeCalendarComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MatCalendar) calendar: MatCalendar<Date>;

  @Input() selectedRangeValue: DateRange<Date>;
  @Output() selectedRangeValueChange = new EventEmitter<DateRange<Date>>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
 }

selectedChange($event) {
const m = moment($event);

if (!isNullOrUndefined(this.selectedRangeValue.end)) {
  const start = this.selectedRangeValue.start;
  // @ts-ignore the parser thinks that this is a date, but it is a moment.js object, so this will work
  start.set(m.toObject());
  this.selectedRangeValue = new DateRange<Date>(start, undefined);
  this.selectedRangeValueChange.emit(this.selectedRangeValue);
} else {
  const end = (!isNullOrUndefined(this.selectedRangeValue.end)) ? this.selectedRangeValue.end : moment(m);
  // @ts-ignore the parser thinks that this is a date, but it is a moment.js object, so this will work
  end.set(m.toObject());
  // @ts-ignore the parser thinks that this is a date, but it is a moment.js object, so this will work
  this.selectedRangeValue = new DateRange<Date>(this.selectedRangeValue.start, end);
  if (this.selectedRangeValue.end < this.selectedRangeValue.start)  {
    this.selectedRangeValue = new DateRange<Date>(this.selectedRangeValue.end, this.selectedRangeValue.start);
  }
  this.selectedRangeValueChange.emit(this.selectedRangeValue);
}
}

}
```

Hope this may help someone.

Comment: Oh My - while this is working like a charm using chrome 86, in Firefox (old 52 as well as modern 88) the ranged inline calendar need double clicks instead of single clicks when selecting start or end date.

Comment: Ok, replacing usage of the selectstart event with selectedChange event fixes the Firefox issue while making the code easier (no more string parsing, just direct usage of moment,js dates)

Comment: Thanks for sharing it helped. I made a small project in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e28yrv-ficvu1?file=src/app/datepicker-inline-calendar-example.ts) to recreate this component

Comment: @VinceH Thank you for creating the stackblitz.  I never had the Time to learn how to do that. It will help other to understand how to solve this Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hy, after some real use case, my solution, is have startDate & endDate as part of component class. In my case have 1 month pre-selected and works very well.

HTML

```
<mat-calendar 
  [selected]="dateRange" 
  [maxDate]="maxDate" 
  (selectedChange)="selectedChange($event)">
</mat-calendar>
```

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatCalendar, DateRange, MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY, DefaultMatCalendarRangeStrategy } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { hasValue } from 'common/utils'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-send-report',
    templateUrl: './send-report.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./send-report.component.scss'],
    providers: [{
        provide: MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY,
        useClass: DefaultMatCalendarRangeStrategy
    }]
})
export class SendReportComponent implements OnInit {

    startDate: Date;
    endDate: Date;
    maxDate: Date;

    @ViewChild(MatCalendar) calendar: MatCalendar<Date>;

    constructor(){

        this.endDate = new Date();

        this.startDate = new Date(this.endDate);
        this.startDate.setMonth(this.startDate.getMonth() - 1);

        this.maxDate = new Date();
        this.dateRange = new DateRange<Date>(this.startDate, this.endDate);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void { }

    dateRange: DateRange<Date>;

    selectedChange(m: any) {

        if (hasValue(this.startDate) && hasValue(this.endDate)) {
            //both has value, reset range picker interval
            this.dateRange = new DateRange<Date>(m, null);
        }
        else {

            let start = this.dateRange.start,
                end = m;

            if (end < start)
                this.dateRange = new DateRange<Date>(end, start);
            else
                this.dateRange = new DateRange<Date>(start, end);
        }

        this.startDate = this.dateRange.start;
        this.endDate = this.dateRange.end;

    }
}
```