# How to highlight months dynamically in Angular Material datepicker?

Tags: angular-material, mat-datepicker

I can't find documentation for selected month for Angular Material Calendar highlight month.I want to show calendar with Month (3 months) highlighted and these month values are coming from Backend Data Respond. And when user able to change another month auto selected to 3 months.

For example, while I click on June, next two month July and August should selected as like the below image.

[image]

Comment: Angular Material has a dateClass input which works with highlighting days, not sure if it works with months.
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#highlighting-specific-dates

Comment: have got answer for Highlight Month 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62980284/how-to-highlight-custom-months-and-years-in-angular-material-datepicker/62986408?noredirect=1#comment111457629_62986408