# Angular material datepicker limit the range selection

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I have an angular material date picker of ranges (start date and end date).

Currently, it is free-selection. Meaning, I can choose any start date and any end date. I'd like to change it a bit. I want it to limit up to 7 days difference. I do not want to allow the user to choose 2 dates with the difference in days is more than 7.

So inside the calendar: [it looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zgkx.png)

As you can see, 5th October is the start date, and it allows us to choose 17th October as the end date. But I want the user to be limited to choose the end date only in the range of 5th October to 12th October (7 days difference maximum).

Is there a way?

This is my HTML:

```html
<mat-form-field class="datepicker" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Enter a date range</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="rangeForm" [rangePicker]="picker" [max]="maxDate">
        <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date" readonly>
        <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date" readonly>
    </mat-date-range-input>
```

Typescript:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-chart',
    templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./chart.component.scss']
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
    private _startDate: moment.Moment = moment().subtract(6, 'days');
    private _endData: moment.Moment = moment();
    
    public maxDate: Date = this._endData.toDate();
    public rangeForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        start: new FormControl(this._startDate.toDate()),
        end: new FormControl(this._endData.toDate()),
    });
    
    constructor() { }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
    
    /**
    * Getter for start date
    * @returns string
    */
    public getStartDate(): string {
        return this._startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    }
    
    /**
    * Getter for end date
    * @returns string
    */
    public getEndDate(): string {
        return this._endData.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Here, https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-date-selection-logic

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Implementing a MatDateRangeSelectionStrategy,

We create a provider like

```js
@Injectable()
export class MaxRangeSelectionStrategy<D> implements MatDateRangeSelectionStrategy<D> {
    start: any;

    constructor(
        @Inject('rangeMax') private delta: number,
        private _dateAdapter: DateAdapter<D>
    ) {}

    selectionFinished(date: D, currentRange: DateRange<D>) {
        let { start, end } = currentRange;
        if (start == null || (start && end)) {
            start = date;
            end = null;
        } else if (end == null) {
            const maxDate = this._dateAdapter.addCalendarDays(start, this.delta);
            end = date ? date > maxDate ? maxDate : date : null;
        }

        return new DateRange<D>(start, end);
    }

    createPreview(activeDate: D | null, currentRange: DateRange<D>): DateRange<D> {
        if (currentRange.start && !currentRange.end) {
            const maxDate = this._dateAdapter.addCalendarDays(currentRange.start, this.delta);
            const rangeEnd = activeDate ? activeDate > maxDate ? maxDate : activeDate : null;
            return new DateRange(currentRange.start, rangeEnd);
        }

        return new DateRange<D>(null, null);
    }
}
```

You can use in directily in your component like

```js
@Component({
  selector: "date-range-picker-selection-strategy-example",
  templateUrl: "date-range-picker-selection-strategy-example.html",
  providers: [
    {provide: 'rangeMax', useValue: 5},
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY,
      useClass: MaxRangeSelectionStrategy
    }
  ]
})
export class DateRangePickerSelectionStrategyExample {}
```

But it's better create a Directive (don't forget declare in your module)

For this, first replace the constructor of the MaxRangeSelectionStrategy to remove the `@Inject('rangeMax')` and declare the variable delta:

```js
  public delta: number; //<--get out of constructor and make public
  constructor(private _dateAdapter: DateAdapter<D>) {}
```

Now create the directive:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: "[maxRange]",
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY,
      useClass: MaxRangeSelectionStrategy
    }
  ]
})
export class MaxRangeDirective {
  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DATE_RANGE_SELECTION_STRATEGY)
    private maxRangeStrategy: MaxRangeSelectionStrategy<any>
  ) {}
  @Input() set maxRange(value: number) {
    this.maxRangeStrategy.delta = +value || 7;
  }
}
```

And use in the .html

```
<mat-date-range-picker maxRange=5 #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
```

At last, We can add in styles.scss a .css like

```
.mat-calendar-body-preview-end> .mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)!important;
}
```

To mark as selected the last element

See [the stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzkcmw?file=src/app/date-range-picker-selection-strategy-example.ts)

**Update** if we has a mat-calendar. the approach is different. Only we need use the dateClass property.

```
<mat-calendar #cal name="fecha" 
              [selected]="fecha" 
              (selectedChange)="fecha=$event;redraw(cal)"
              [dateClass]="dateClass">
</mat-calendar>
```

Where, e.g.

```
dateClass=(date: any) => {
  const days =
    (date.getTime() - this.fecha.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  return days >= 0 && days < 5 ? 'red' : null;
};

redraw(cal:MatCalendar<any>)
{
    cal.updateTodaysDate() 
}
```

And we has in styles.css

```
.mat-calendar-body-cell.red {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work when applied to just a <mat-calendar>

Comment: @h11, if you only has a mat-calendar, the approach is other (only use the property `dateClass`, I update the question, I hope can help you

Comment: How to prevent the user from manually typing in an invalid date range with this approach? This validation only seems to be applied when the user selects the date range via the calendar.

Answer (score 1):

This is better than the previous answer, one main flaw in previous answer is, you will able to select the end date less than start date, which should actually be invalid.

Below is best and simple way of implementing. By setting the maxDate for the daterange

*html file*

```
 <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker" [max]="maxDate" >
      <input matStartDate placeholder="From Date" required formControlName="fromDate"  (dateChange)="setMaxDate()" >
      <input matEndDate placeholder="To Date" required formControlName="toDate" >
 </mat-date-range-input>

 <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
 <mat-date-range-picker (closed)="resetMaxDate()" #picker disabled="false"></mat-date-range-picker>
```

*component.ts file*

```
resetMaxDate()                                                          
{
  if(this.dateRangeForm.get('toDate').value )                             
  {                                                            
    this.maxDate = new Date(2122,1);
  }                                                                      
}


setMaxDate().                                                           
{
  let tempdate = new Date(this.dateRangeForm.get('fromDate').value);
  tempdate.setDate(tempdate.getDate() + 30);
  this.maxDate = new Date(tempdate);                                    
}
```

**can also add validators for manual input also**

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder)                           
{
  this.dateRangeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fromDate: new FormControl(new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000*3600*24*6), Validators.nullValidator),
      toDate: new FormControl(new Date(), [Validators.nullValidator,this.dateRangeValidator])
});         }




private dateRangeValidator: ValidatorFn = (): { [key: string]: any; } | null => {
  let invalid = false;
  const from = this.dateRangeForm && 
  this.dateRangeForm.get("fromDate").value;
  const to = this.dateRangeForm && this.dateRangeForm.get("toDate").value;
  if (from && to) {
    invalid = new Date(from).valueOf() + 1000*3600*24*30 < new Date(to).valueOf()  //checking if date difference is less than 31 days
}
  return invalid ? { invalidRange: { from, to } } : null;     };
```