# Multi select check box drop down list with search list item facility in angular 11

Tags: angular, dropdownlistfor

I want to develop a multi select check box drop down list with search facility in angular 11.

I tried following link
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/multi-select-dropdown-in-angular/

But this supports for angular version 14. I want to develop the same feature as in above link.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You can try to install older version of `ng-multiselect-dropdown` which will be compatible with Angular 11.

Comment: Downgrade to the dependency to version `0.3.8`. ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown/v/0.3.8

Comment: Some time ago someone ask some like you in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223829/is-there-any-dropdown-available-with-filter-feature-in-angular-material-nb-usi/60249294#60249294). Currently I would use [cdk-overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/examples) -it's not related to material-angular, only with angular/cdk- like this another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73905665/how-to-build-a-colour-pallete-in-dropdown-in-angular/73908751#73908751)

Comment: @paranaan  it is not showing any error. code is compiling successfully but the dropdown list is blank. Nothing is getting displayed.